# Slideshow with indicator CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi I am trying to figure out how to display images when clicked on a section on my bar. So far I have a working animation to switch between sections but I would like to **display images under it**. It's my first time doing this so I absolutely don't know how to do this and would very much appreciate the help.

```js
var indicator = document.querySelector('.stefan-indicator');
    var items = document.querySelectorAll('.stefan-item');

    function handleIndicator(el) {
        items.forEach(function (item) {
          item.classList.remove('is-active');
          item.removeAttribute('style');
        });
        indicator.style.width = "".concat(el.offsetWidth, "px");
        indicator.style.left = "".concat(el.offsetLeft, "px");
        indicator.style.backgroundColor = el.getAttribute('active-color');
        el.classList.add('is-active');
        el.style.color = el.getAttribute('active-color');
      }
      
      items.forEach(function (item, index) {
        item.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
          handleIndicator(e.target);
        });
        item.classList.contains('is-active') && handleIndicator(item);
      });
```

```css
.stefan {
    margin-top:4%;
    display: inline-flex;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100%;
    background-color: inherit;
    padding: 0 20px;
    border-radius: 40px;
    /* box-shadow: 0 10px 40px rgba(159, 162, 177, .8); */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
.stefan-item {
    color: #252525;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: 0.3s;
    margin: 0 6px;
    z-index: 1;
    font-family: 'Open sans', sans-serif;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: 500;
}
.stefan-item:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -6px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #ffb833;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.3s;
}
.stefan-item:not(.is-active):hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 0;
}
.stefan-item:not(.is-active):hover {
    color: #ffb833;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.stefan-indicator {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 4px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    height: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
    border-radius: 8px 8px 0 0;
}
```

```html
                <div class="stefan">
                            <a class="stefan-item is-active" active-color="#ffb833">Section1</a>
                            <a class="stefan-item" active-color="#ffb833">Section2</a>
                            <a class="stefan-item" active-color="#ffb833">Section3</a>
                            <a class="stefan-item" active-color="#ffb833">Section4</a>
                            <a class="stefan-item" active-color="#ffb833">Section5</a>
                            <span class="stefan-indicator"></span>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you are trying to do is build tabs component you need to create elements for every tab that are hidden by default and only are displayed when your code tells it to.

So when stefan-item with section1 content is clicked, your javascript should tell stefan-content-1 to change it's style to display:block (by directly changing style or adding class).

You can have a look here: https://web.dev/building-a-tabs-component/ or use a ready made component. Bootstrap, Material UI and other systems have tabs for the taking.